# pandas read_html error: unexpected keyword argument 'max_rows'

Tags: pandas, python-3.7

I'm trying to write a scraper to scrape Option prices from Yahoo Finance. The code below is working and even gives the correct output answer. The problem is that right before the answer, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    343             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)
    344             if method is not None:
--> 345                 return method()
    346             return None
    347         else:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _repr_html_(self)
    694         See Also
    695         --------
--> 696         to_html : Convert DataFrame to HTML.
    697 
    698         Examples

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in to_html(self, buf, columns, col_space, header, index, na_rep, formatters, float_format, sparsify, index_names, justify, bold_rows, classes, escape, max_rows, max_cols, show_dimensions, notebook, decimal, border, table_id)
   2035             Dictionary mapping columns containing datetime types to stata
   2036             internal format to use when writing the dates. Options are 'tc',
-> 2037             'td', 'tm', 'tw', 'th', 'tq', 'ty'. Column can be either an integer
   2038             or a name. Datetime columns that do not have a conversion type
   2039             specified will be converted to 'tc'. Raises NotImplementedError if

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py in to_html(self, classes, notebook, border)
    751             need_leadsp = dict(zip(fmt_columns, map(is_numeric_dtype, dtypes)))
    752 
--> 753             def space_format(x, y):
    754                 if (y not in self.formatters and
    755                         need_leadsp[x] and not restrict_formatting):

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_rows'
```

I tried researching the cause of the error in different stackoverflow questions, as well as the github repo of the pandas library. The closest thing I found was in the what's new section of the pandas 0.24.0 "max_rows and max_cols parameters removed from HTMLFormatter since truncation is handled by DataFrameFormatter [GH23818](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/23818)"

My code is as follows:

```py
import lxml
import requests
from time import sleep

ticker = 'AAPL'

url = "http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%s/options?p=%s"%(ticker,ticker)
response = requests.get(url, verify=False)
print ("Parsing %s"%(url))
sleep(15)
parser = lxml.html.fromstring(response.text)

tables = parser.xpath('//table')
print(len(tables))

puts = lxml.etree.tostring(tables[1], method='html')

df = pd.read_html(puts, flavor='bs4')[0]

df.tail()
```

The df.tail() shows correctly the last 5 rows of the table, but I can't seem to remove the error. Also every time I use the dataframe, I get a correct result, but the error is shown again.

Thanks in advance in helping with my error.

Comment: I have ran it on my computer (python3.7) I had not seen this problem. But it seems that you use anaconda. I do not, I only pip install everything I need. The issue might come from the anaconda install.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot @RenauV. I uninstalled anaconda, and pip installed everything again. It worked perfectly. Thanks a million :)

Comment: NP - I will post the answer. You will be able to confirm it so that we can close the question.

Comment: I'm not allowed to upvote since I don't have 15 reputations yet but thank you so much for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference:

The error was driven by the anaconda install of the packages.
By pip installing the packages, the error goes away.
BR